# Crop just added a picture

Tags: jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap, jcrop, live-preview

I'm using for file-input preview `bootstrap-fileinput.js` by Arnold Daniels. And for cropping `jquery.Jcrop.js` by Kelly Hallman.

`bootstrap-fileinput` for live-preview just selected image, insert in image `src` encoded data URL. Something like this `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw.......`

When the user selects the photo and get the live-preview, I wanted to allow them to crop that image. I tried to do that with an additional button: When the user chose an image they'd get a live-preview, and when they click on button "crop", then for just added image will initialized `Jcrop` script. (`$img_wrapper.find('img').Jcrop({});`). And it works, all fine.

But when I try to do the same, without pressing "crop" button, but automatically after file selected, it doesn't work.  As I understand, jQuery doesn't see the new image.
I tried with event `on.('click', func...` and it's dont work. Then i found in documentation (http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput) that `Jcrop` provides her own listener `on.('change.bs.fileinput', funct...` but it still does not work. So with button "crop" works fine, automatically doesn't work, why?

---

So, that way it works:
(try select image, press "crop", and you can crop image)
http://jsfiddle.net/8f44yo9v/2/

But that way, doesn't work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/o7tbr6mo/

Comment: For action `$(#file-input).on('change', funct...` the same result, dont initialize crop for just added image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found (not the best) solution to do that.

In library `bootstrap-fileinput.js`, on line №86, there's declared variable `var $img = $('<img>')`, this is the image DOM which will be added like thumbnail for live preview. So at the end, of that function we can added out initialize for that image.

```
if (window.location.pathname == '/add_tour') {
      $img.Jcrop({
        aspectRatio: 16/9,
        bgColor: '#3598DC',
        setSelect: [$img.width(), 0, 0, 0],
        minSize: [250, 0]
      });
    }
```

And it would work. But how i think, it's not the best idea to change code in bootstrap library. But  get $img object from that file, to other JS code, i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

The image element is not created yet when the bootstrap-fileinput triggers the "change.bs.fileinput".

You can create a loop to wait for the element:

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change.bs.fileinput', function () {
    var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
        if ($('.fileinput-preview img').length) {
            $('.fileinput-preview img').Jcrop({});
            clearInterval(checkExist);
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

PS: You can check for infinite loops in case the element is not created.

Comment: I like this approach, but as soon as I upload an image greater than 85px tall, it immediately (well, within a fraction of a second) squashes it down to 85px in height. Why?